# direct link past browser site not open php site

Tags: php

when i check online counter some user online my site, i chek there activity suppose thy browsing a page

```
http://example.com/nph6vgevq1c/watch-video--dil-se-1998--all-songs--jukebox--online-video/
```

i copy past that link my browser my site shoing blank for that page no content coming but when i search same content inside my site it open fine with out any issue.

in my error report i see

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/pads/public_html/index.php on line 38

my 38 line php code blew

```
foreach ($json->items as $sam){
        $linkv= $sam->id->videoId;
        $namev= $sam->snippet->title;
```

its was an youtube data api search video script.

Comment: Before `foreach`, you probably need to check `if(isset($json->items))`

Comment: eror gone but that link visit content not come just blank page with site header footer design only

Comment: This means, either the problem is somewhere else in your code. `$json` is not getting populated. You need to check how is `$json` getting populated.